# Google Guava's HashBasedTable.contains() and custom hashCode implementation

Tags: java, hashmap, guava, hashcode

While coding Java, I am using Google Guava's `HashBasedTable` as

```
Table<ClassA, ClassB, Integer> myHashBasedTable = HashBasedTable.create();
```

where I have overriden `hashCode()` and `equals()` of `ClassA` and `ClassB` with the Intellij default syntax.

Now I am encountering weird behavior of the `contains()` method. Even though there is an entry for a combination `(objA, objB)`, `myHashbasedTable.contains(objA, objB)` returns false in certain cases.

I tried to track down the problem as follows:

```
Set<ClassA> setA = myHashBasedTable.rowKeySet();
List<ClassA> listA = new ArrayList(setA);
Set<ClassA> setA_fromList = new HashSet(listA);
```

where for certain `objA` that are contained in `myHashBasedTable`

`setA.contains(objA)` returns false

`listA.contains(objA)` returns true

`setA_fromList.contains(objA)` returns true

Does someone see an explanation for this behavior? Does it have to do with my custom hashCode / equals and how HashBasedTable treats hashes or is there a different cause?

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong without seeing more code. A correct implementation of hascode & equals shouldn't do this. Guava simply uses a `HashMap<R, HashMap<C, V>>` under the hood.

Comment: can you show your hashCode() and equals() code ?

Comment: @Rustam : they are too complex to talk sense into them without context. I am using the Intellij default implementation.

Comment: @zapl : I am aware of "under-hood-structure" of HashBasedTable, which makes the above behavior even more surprising to me...

Comment: If you can't find a reasonable [mcve] that demonstrates this then check manually whether the implementation of intellij managed to be correct: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29 lists all the requirements. Most commonly violated: `equal` objects need to have identical hashcodes.

Comment: @madison54, tested your example with Guava 18 (http://pastebin.com/s13fPNkE), all works correctly.

Comment: The behavior you are describing is consistent with ClassA objects being modified after being put into the table.  Is that happening?